# Find the general integral of the equation $(2x − y)y^2u_x + 8(y −2x)x^2u_y=2(4x^2+y^2)u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find the general integral of the equation $$(2x − y)y^2u_x + 8(y −2x)x^2u_y=2(4x^2+y^2)u;
> u = u(x, y).$$
> and deduce the solution to the Cauchy problem when $u(x, 0) = \frac{1}
> {2x}$
> is on a portion of the x-axis.

I got stuck middle of the problem here is my work

$$ \dfrac{dx}{(2x − y)y^2}= \dfrac{dy}{8(y −2x)x^2}=\dfrac{du}{2(4x^2+y^2)u}$$

by first two I found $z_1=\frac{y^3}{8}+x^3=c_1$ where $c_1$ is arbitrary constant.

Can anyone help me to find one?

Comment: You could try the substitution $(X, Y) = (8 x^3, y^3)$ which simplifies the characteristic curves.

Comment: @Gribouillis can you please show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(2x − y)y^2u_x + 8(y −2x)x^2u_y=2(4x^2+y^2)u$$

$$ \dfrac{dx}{(2x − y)y^2}= \dfrac{dy}{8(y −2x)x^2}=\dfrac{du}{2(4x^2+y^2)u}$$

$$ \dfrac{dx}{y^2}= -\dfrac{dy}{8x^2}=(2x-y)\dfrac{du}{2(4x^2+y^2)u}$$

A first chacracteristic equation comes from solving $\dfrac{dx}{y^2}= -\dfrac{dy}{8x^2}$
$$y^3+8x^3=C_1$$
That is what you found correctly.

A second characteristic equation comes from solving

$ \dfrac{dx}{y^2}= -\dfrac{dy}{8x^2}=\dfrac{2dx-dy}{2y^2+8x^2}=(2x-y)\dfrac{du}{2(4x^2+y^2)u}$

$2dx-dy=(2x-y)\dfrac{du}{u}\quad\implies\quad \dfrac{2dx-dy}{2x-y}=\dfrac{du}{u}$
$$u=(2x-y)C_2$$

The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicite equation $C_2=F(C_1)$ leads to :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=(2x-y)F(y^3+8x^3)}$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).

Condition : $u(x,0)=\frac{1}{2x}$

$u(x,0)=(2x)F(8x^3)=\frac{1}{2x}\quad\implies\quad F(8x^3)=\frac{1}{4x^2}$

Let $\quad X=8x^3 \quad ; \quad x=\frac12 X^{1/3}$

$$F(X)=\frac{1}{X^{2/3}}$$
The function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $X=8x^3+y^3$. This gives the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{2x-y}{(8x^3+y^3)^{2/3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

\begin{equation}\widetilde{u} \left(X , Y\right) = u \left(x , y\right) \qquad  \text{where} \qquad  X = 8 {x}^{3} \quad  \text{and} \qquad  Y = {y}^{3}\end{equation}

One has

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  \begin{array}{rcl}{\widetilde{u}}_{X}-{\widetilde{u}}_{Y}&=&\displaystyle  \frac{d x}{d X} {u}_{x}-\frac{d y}{d Y} {u}_{y}\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{1}{24 {x}^{2}} {u}_{x}-\frac{1}{3 {y}^{2}} {u}_{y} \\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{1}{24 {x}^{2} {y}^{2}} \left({y}^{2} {u}_{x}-8 {x}^{2} {u}_{y}\right) \\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{4 {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}{12 {x}^{2} {y}^{2} \left(2 x-y\right)} \widetilde{u} \left(X , Y\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{1}{3} \  \frac{{Y}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}+{X}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}}{{X}^{\frac{1}{3}}-{Y}^{\frac{1}{3}}} \widetilde{u} \left(X , Y\right)
\end{array}\end{equation}

For a fixed $ \left(X , Y\right)$ let us now define

\begin{equation}{\phi} \left(t\right) = \widetilde{u} \left(X+t , Y-t\right)\end{equation}

One has

\begin{equation}{{\phi}'} \left(t\right) = \frac{1}{3} \  \frac{{\left(X+t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}+{\left(Y-t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}}{{\left(X+t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}-{\left(Y-t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} {\phi} \left(t\right)\end{equation}

Note that $ {\phi} \left(Y\right) = \widetilde{u} \left(X+Y , 0\right) = {\left(X+Y\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{3}}}$ by the given boundary condition. It follows that

\begin{equation}\widetilde{u} \left(X , Y\right) = {\phi} \left(0\right) = {\left(X+Y\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{3}}} \exp  \left({-\frac{1}{3}} \int_{0}^{Y}\frac{{\left(X+t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}+{\left(Y-t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}}{{\left(X+t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}-{\left(Y-t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} d t\right)\end{equation}

hence

\begin{equation}u \left(x , y\right) = {\left(8 {x}^{3}+{y}^{3}\right)}^{{-\frac{1}{3}}} \exp  \left({-\frac{1}{3}} \int_{0}^{{y}^{3}}\frac{{\left(8 {x}^{3}+t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}+{\left({y}^{3}-t\right)}^{{-\frac{2}{3}}}}{{\left(8 {x}^{3}+t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}-{\left({y}^{3}-t\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} d t\right)\end{equation}

**Exercise**: check the result by direct derivation.

**Edit**: Due to the denominator below the integral sign, it seems that this formula is valid only in the domain $|Y|<|X|$ or equivalently $|y| < 2 |x|$. Indeed, under this assumption, the quantity $(X+t)^{1/3}-(Y-t)^{1/3}$ cannot vanish in the interval $t\in (0, Y)$. This problem arises because the factor $(2 x -y)$ in the equation makes the line $y=2x$ singular. It is plausible that the solution must be extended by $0$ on the rest of ${\mathbb R}^2$, that is to say in the region $|Y|\ge|X|$, but this requires additional arguments.